# how to sloved Text Overflowed in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have added text widget inside row widget.then 2nd text value

```
Text(
                      widget.leavemodel.reason ?? '',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
```

getting 4 pixcel overflowed.how can i sloved this?

code is bello

```
 Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Reason :',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.leavemodel.reason ?? '',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

solution for text overflowed in flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two ways:

1. Box Constraints [image: box constraint]
   [image]
2. Wrap widget instead of the row [image]
   [image]

BEST WAY HERE THOUGH IS TO USE A WRAP WIDGET...

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `Text` widget with `Expanded`:

```
Expanded(
 child: Text(
      'Reason :',
         style:
          TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),)
```